# How can I fire touchcancel event in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I found some tutorials and stepguide how to trigger Javascript click events, but I do not know how can I fire a `touchcancel` event in **native Javascript**?

```
var event = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
event.initEvent("touchcancel", true, true);
event.synthetic = true;
document.dispatchEvent(event, true);
```

I have used the `"MouseEvents"`, because the `"TouchEvents"` parameter will thrown error.

But this above code is not working.

I would like to trigger `"touchcancel"` event, because sometimes there is too much `pointer` and I saw that the browser can call 'touchcancel' and it will clear this pointers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.addEventListener("touchstart", function() { return false; });`

Comment: I know this. But I do not want to listen, I want to fire the "touchstart" event!